# Remove specific files in a folder using powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to remove specific text files from my folder (D:\Test) using powershell script. Below are the list of files i have in my folder and need to remove files with name "Defrag" in the file name.

1. Test.txt
2. Log.txt
3. Defrag_20180111.txt
4. Defrag_20180110.txt

I need to remove the files with name "Defrag".

Thanks for your help in advance.

Pratap

Answer (score 11):

PowerShell is really powerful.  This one can be done with one line:

```
Remove-Item -Path "pathtoyourfile\*Defrag*.txt"
```

And to your second question:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "pathtoyourfile\*Defrag*.txt" -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-15) } | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: Thank you, Also i how can we remove files which are 10 days older?

Comment: 2nd answer now there

Comment: Is there any way we could log the list of file names into a sql table which will get deleted?  Thank you very much for your quick response.

Comment: see this page on accessing sql server from powershell - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh289310.aspx

Comment: @prathapkasthuri Please ask one question at a time and preferably show some research effort. These questions already have many answers here on SO.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Matt, I will do!

Answer (score 0):

How about `Get-ChildItem * -Include *Defrag* -Recurse | Remove-Item` from [Delete File in Subfolders Recursively by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.3#example-4-delete-files-in-subfolders-recursively)?